# Removing Words from word cloud in R

Tags: r, word-cloud

I am able to make word cloud, but my problem is when I take the frequency of word counts, I get words whose frequency is 1. I want words whose frequency is greater than 2. How can I do that?

tdm is just a term matrix. I tried with something like `rowSums(m>2)`, but its not working

```
# define tdm as matrix
m = as.matrix(tdm)
# get word counts in decreasing order
word_freqs = sort(rowSums(m), decreasing=TRUE) 
# create a data frame with words and their frequencies
dm = data.frame(word=names(word_freqs), freq=word_freqs)
```

Trying to make from https://sites.google.com/site/miningtwitter/questions/talking-about/wordclouds/wordcloud1

Comment: have a look here: http://groupspaces.com/KCRUsersGroup/wiki/wordcloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply filter `word_freqs` before constructing the data.frame:

```
word_freqs <- word_freqs[word_freqs > 2]
```

Comment: great..thanks..
@Manetheran..can u tell me one more thing, if i want only top 2 words, then how can i compute it ?

Comment: Well since you already have the words sorted in decreasing order, you can just take the first two elements: `word_freqs <- word_freqs[1:2]`.

Comment: or even just `dm[1:2,]`

Comment: Useful solution! I only knew how to filter them before making a TDM, not after. Btw, if you want to expand this to n-gram word clouds check this out: http://hack-r.com/?p=35