# Removing specific words from word cloud in R

Tags: r, word-cloud

I have made a word cloud in R for 2 songs. Now in the tdm when I display the items, i get the frequency of words for song 1 and song 2. I am also able to print the word cloud perfectly. My problem is i do not want words in tdm who frequency is less than 2. How can I do that.

I wrote the code and got this output:

```
tdm=TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)

> tdm=as.matrix(tdm)
>
> tdm
>

song 1  song 2
act                   0  2
action                0  2
actions               0  1
activity              5  4
```

I only want word activity as it occur more than once in both the songs. 
I mean I want to remove the words, act, action, actions. How can I do that  ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing Words from word cloud in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111432/removing-words-from-word-cloud-in-r)

Comment: No, it is not the exact duplicate.

Comment: Which package are you using?  Is it the `tm` package?  If the code you wrote is not too long consider adding it to your post with a small data set to make your example reproducible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't provide data some something like this should work:

```
data("crude")
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude)

x <- as.matrix(tdm)[, 1:2]
x[rowSums(apply(x, 2, ">", 1)) == 2, ]
```

Explanation: The line `x <- as.matrix(tdm)[, 1:2]` just getting 2 columns like your data so it doesn't do anything but needed to make data that looked like yours since you didn't provide any.  This line `apply(x, 2, ">", 1)` says give me logical values for the statement is this greater than 1.  Then I wrap this with `rowSums` (logical values are TRUE=1 and FALSE=0). Values equal to 2 (I had `> 1` before but this is sloppy) are the conditions you're looking for.  The I use a logical index with this output `x[GRAB_THE_ROWS, ]`.  You can tear each step apart and run the code for yourself as seen below:

```
(step_1 <- apply(x, 2, ">", 1))
(step_2 <- rowSums(step_1))
(step_3 <- step_2 == 2)
x[step_3, ]
```

Comment: It worked, but can u please explain this two lines, i am unable to get it